# wx.SingleInstanceChecker reporting nonexistent instance, even through reboot (Under Windows)

Tags: windows, singleton, wxpython, mutex, wxwidgets

I've been trying to use wx.SingleInstanceChecker to avoid running one
of my apps more than once (My windows screen gets cluttered with windows often).  I based code on the example given in the [documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.SingleInstanceChecker.html#wx-singleinstancechecker). Here is the code:

```
class SingleApp(wx.App):
"""
class that extends wx.App and only permits a single running instance.
"""

def OnInit(self):
    """
    wx.App init function that returns False if the app is already running.
    """
    self.name = "Program_Runner-%s".format(wx.GetUserId())
    self.instance = wx.SingleInstanceChecker(self.name,path='lockfiles') # actually path isn't used in Win32
    if self.instance.IsAnotherRunning():
        wx.MessageBox(
            "An instance of the application is already running.", 
            "Error", 
             wx.OK| wx.ICON_WARNING
        )
        return False
    return True
```

At first it worked fine, but then at some point, it was telling me "Another
Instance already running", even when all were shut down.

Even after shutting down the computer completely and restarting it, I try to run the program and it still reports there's another instance running.

If I edit the program and change the argument by even a single letter, it starts working properly.

I tried redirecting the "lock file" directory using the path keyword, but with further research, found out that this "lock file" technique is only under Linux.  Apparently the Windows implementation uses named mutexes.  (Confirmation of this would be nice)

So I can't look for file system changes, because the mutex is an os thing.
So then, why would the original named mutex persist, even through power cycling? Real shutdown, not just hibernating.  I could understand a mutex not going away if a program is abnormally terminated.  But not through a power cycle.

Some people might say: "Just use the new argument and don't worry about it."
But there must be a way to unlock that old mutex, because it is a situation that's bound to recur.

It did recur, then I changed it back to the old key/name and it worked again.  This is a low bandwidth issue for me, but curious nonetheless.

Comment: From the docs: create() Returns False if initialization failed, it doesn’t mean that another instance is running IsAnotherRunning to check for it. Alert the user about the problem and offer to continue execution without checking if another instance is running.

Comment: Hi Rolf,
   I edited my original post, adding the code I was using to make it clear I was using the function as documented.

Comment: Perhaps this might help. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474070/

Comment: That example is about 10 years old, so I would assume something similar to that is what is used by the wx.SingleInstanceChecker, only I can't dig down into the code because it calls wxwidget code (non-Python).  I'll try it, nevertheless.

Comment: You could always lock (bind) a tcp port instead.

Comment: I've also done that, which of course has the added advantage of being able to "wake up" the Singleton app and pass it arguments or simply bring the window to the front.   I was just hoping the built-in function would work as advertised.   Since it didn't seem to, I was trying to discover why.  Incidentally that older version which explicitly creates a mutex, seems to exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Time to embrace Unix/Linux ?